# How to convert monthly return to yearly return after checking if all 12 months are present in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have monthly returns and i want to convert them into yearly returns for each company (using cusip6, i am using CRSP data). I also want to keep only those years which have all the 12 months. I am currently using the following code, but i would like to know if there is inbuilt functions in pandas that can do this?`

```
def monthly_to_ann_ret(data):
    """ funtion to check if all 12 months are present and
        calculate yearly returns from monthly returns
    """
    data['year'] = data['date'].dt.year 
    data.sort(['cusip6','year'],inplace = True)
    data_grouped = data.groupby(['cusip6','year'])
    annual_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for name,group in data_grouped:
        if group.shape[0] == 12:
            group.loc['RET'] = 1 + group['RET']
            group['yearly_RET'] = group['RET'].cumprod() - 1
            annual_df = annual_df.append(group.iloc[-1])
        else:
            continue
    return annual_df`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks pretty good to me.  Here's an alternative approach FWIW that is a little more concise and use `nth` as a bit of a shortcut.

Here's some sample data that is 46 months for 2 firms (just missing the very first month and very last month).

```
stocks = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'cusip6':np.repeat( [1234,5678], 24 ),
    'date':np.tile( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=24, freq='M'), 2 ),
    'return':(np.random.choice([1.005,1.010,1.015],48)) })
stocks = stocks.iloc[1:-1]
```

Then with some groupby stuff including `nth` you can do this fairly compactly.

```
stocks['year']=stocks.date.dt.year
stocks['cum_return'] = stocks.groupby(['cusip6','year']).cumprod()
stocks.groupby(['cusip6','year']).nth(11)

             cum_return       date  return
cusip6 year                               
1234   2012    1.115614 2012-12-31   1.010
5678   2011    1.149248 2011-12-31   1.015
```

And for comparison, if we had used `tail(1)` instead of `nth(11)` we would just be getting the last month whether it is the 11th or 12th month.

```
stocks.groupby(['cusip6','year']).tail(1)

    cusip6       date  return  year  cum_return
11    1234 2011-12-31   1.010  2011    1.110064
23    1234 2012-12-31   1.010  2012    1.115614
35    5678 2011-12-31   1.015  2011    1.149248
46    5678 2012-11-30   1.015  2012    1.126687
```

Comment: Thanks. That's better, didn't know about the nth function.